# How to create multiple channels with different receivers? Spring Redis pub/sub

Tags: java, spring, redis, publish-subscribe, spring-jms

I'm using Redis Publish Subscribe through Spring Data, but I'm having problems to add more than 1 Channel.

Currently I'm following the typical examples where the MessageListenerContainer is configured by adding a MessageListenerAdapter which has associated a Receiver class, as following:

[image]

The previous works perfectly and I'm able to push and receive messages.
However one I try to add a second listener adapter for creating a "channel with a differente receiver and I'm getting a NullPointerException.

[image]

The error is attached below. Is there a different way to adding a new adapter? In general I would like to add channels dynamically.

It is possible to add multiple channels associated with one specific receiver by providing a PatternTopic list at addMessageListener method.

Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is an important bug with Spring Redis when adding MessageListenerAdapter.

If the **Receiver** class does not extend from **MessageListener** (and so, implements onMessage) the inner method MethodInvoker() from MessageListenerAdapter class specifically ask if the Receiver is instance of MessageListener (see last line of image below).

[image]

To solve this problem just extend from **MessageListener** and then you can add the additional adapters directly.

It's a shame that spring-data-redis team do not enable issues in their github page to publish this bug. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis

Comment: I already check its source code and AFIAK its not really the `bug` from them. You can either custom the `MessageListenerAdapter` or qualifier list of adapter to add into the `container` like below answer

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking, use below configuration for Spring Boot 1.5.X

`RedisConfig` class for multiple channels:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                            @Qualifier("notificationListenerAdapter") MessageListenerAdapter notificationListenerAdapter,
                                            @Qualifier("countListenerAdapter") MessageListenerAdapter countListenerAdapter) {

        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.addMessageListener(notificationListenerAdapter,  new PatternTopic("notification"));
        container.addMessageListener(countListenerAdapter, new PatternTopic("count"));
        return container;
    }

    @Bean("notificationListenerAdapter")
    MessageListenerAdapter notificationListenerAdapter(RedisReceiver redisReceiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(redisReceiver, "receiveNotificationMessage");
    }

    @Bean("countListenerAdapter")
    MessageListenerAdapter countListenerAdapter(RedisReceiver redisReceiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(redisReceiver, "receiveCountMessage");
    }

    @Bean
    RedisReceiver receiver() {
        return new RedisReceiver();
    }

    @Bean
    StringRedisTemplate template(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new StringRedisTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

}
```

`RedisReceiver` to receive messages from channels.

**Note**: Make sure the method name matches the method names defined above.

```
public class RedisReceiver {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisReceiver.class);


    public void receiveNotificationMessage(String message) {
        LOGGER.info("Message Received from notification channel: <" + message + ">");

    }

    public void receiveCountMessage(String message) {
        LOGGER.info("Message Received from count channel: <" + message + ">");
    }
}
```

Test the flow:

```
public class TestMessages {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestMessages.class);

    private final StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    public TestMessages(StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

    public void sendNotification(String message) {

        redisTemplate.convertAndSend("notification", message);

    }

    public void sendCount(String message) {

        redisTemplate.convertAndSend("count", message);

    }
}
```